# Create TAG's using ANT script to SVN

Tags: tags, build.xml

Currently we are using ANT (build.xml) script to create WAR or JAR files and deploy. Now I would like to create TAG's whenever a build is triggered using the script or methods to create a TAG in SVN for a project whenever a build is triggered. If it is possible can someone give the parameters to add in the script.

I appreciate for the response.

Comment: Can someone help..?

Comment: Is there anyone who can be helped with this?